# Convert to dateTime from string (arabic culture to english)

Tags: c#

```
string strHijdt ="29-02-1435";

    DateTime hdt = DateTime.ParseExact(strHijdt, "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:MI24",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Getting error while convert to string("29-02-1435") to datetime

Comment: using parse exact you are providing exact format, but your format does not match string

Answer (score 0):

`2/1435` has `28` days only

so, below will work

```
string aa="28-02-1435";
DateTime hdt = DateTime.ParseExact(aa, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(hdt.ToLongDateString());
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/vSKJCi)

since you have given input as `29-02-1435` even  you provide correct date time format (`dd-MM-yyyy`) you will get error for the invalid date

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:
1. As mentioned above, expected format for does not match string (there is no time, different separator)
2. If your date string is in Hijri calendar, you should either provide correct culture explicitly or use system culture (pass null for IFormatProvider):

```
string strHijdt = "29-02-1435";
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA");
DateTime hdt = DateTime.ParseExact(strHijdt, "dd-MM-yyyy", culture);
```

Comment: its not working. i checked with what u mentioned changes in above. but result is failure

Comment: what is the failure? Dont use ToLongDateString() since it will print the date in gregorian/english format, try `Console.WriteLine(hdt.ToString(culture));` instead